# What is exports.local used for in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, passport.js, node-modules

[Exports.local Node js sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZCEM.jpg)

I am using passport-local-mongoose in my node js Application and I come across exports.local for passport authentication. I couldn't understand it function. Please check the image above

Answer (score 1):

In your case here there is nothing special about `local` keyword, it is just the name of the variable that is used to export the passport local authentication strategy configuration, so you can call it in other files using `require`, so here in your example, you have this logic written in `authenticate.js`, so to use it in any other file you will have to call it using the following:

```
const { local } =  require('./authenticate'); // identify the right path to authenticate.js
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The CommonJS (CJS) format is used in Node.js and uses require and module.exports to define dependencies and modules. The npm ecosystem is built upon this format. In your case `exports.local` creates a new module and export it for the use elsewhere.

Example
user.js

```
const getName = () => {
   return 'Jim';
};

exports.getName = getName;
```

index.js

```
const user = require('./user');
console.log(`User: ${user.getName()}`);
```

Output

> User: Jim